# Can co-mutations be potential expression quantitative trait loci (eQTLs)?

Tags: gene-expression, mutations, gwas

I'm wondering if it is possible to test this and how? Usually we do this for single SNPs, I wanted to know if it was plausible for pairs of SNPs. Which method would you suggest?

I want to test whether the co-occurrance of mutations has an impact on expression levels.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into tests for epistasis in eQTL analysis, [here is a paper I found readily](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/31/5/656/318277), here is another [tool](https://www.nature.com/articles/gene201615)